# Im trying to integrtae redux-persist as mentioned in the docs, everything seems well but it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I need to persist data using redux-persist. I am using a React redux toolkit boilerplate, I integrated the library as mentioned in the docs but it doesn't seem to work, there are no errors and I don't know where the issue is, can anyone help me please ?

Here is the the configureStore:

[configureStore.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAtxo.png)

And here is the index:

[index.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCzC3.png)

PS: there is an item in localStorage persist:root as configured in the persistConfig:

[localStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGODI.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of screenshots. A [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will be great

Comment: as @slideshowp2 says please share your code into snippets to help you better, also  check this topic about [Why not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)